# Can I change Django's "Starting development server" link?

Tags: python, django

When I start my in-development Django site I get the following message:

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
August 15, 2017 - 12:03:00
Django version 1.11.3, using settings 'mysite.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

It would be convenient to just click the provided link. However, 127.0.0.1 is not one of my ALLOWED_HOSTS, so it doesn't work. Can I set or override this message so that it uses a valid link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[From the runserver documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/django-admin/#runserver):

> `django-admin runserver [addrport]`
>
> Starts a lightweight development Web server on the local machine. By default, the server runs on port 8000 on the IP address 127.0.0.1. You can pass in an IP address and port number explicitly.
>
> ...
>
> Note that the default IP address, 127.0.0.1, is not accessible from other machines on your network. To make your development server viewable to other machines on the network, use its own IP address (e.g. 192.168.2.1) or 0.0.0.0 or :: (with IPv6 enabled).
>
> You can provide an IPv6 address surrounded by brackets (e.g. [200a::1]:8000). This will automatically enable IPv6 support.
>
> A hostname containing ASCII-only characters can also be used.

So you can simply use:

```
./manage.py runserver localhost:8000
```

Comment: But what solution to REALLY change the message. I run development server under the Nginx, so I want Django to print http://server.local/ without any port number, but still use 8000 port for its server.

Comment: This is not the answer! How can someone change the message. If you just pass in the command line then you can type in the browser address bar.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible if you override the `runserver` command and set `default_addr` in the `Command` class as class attribute.

Follow these steps

1. Create a your [own management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/howto/custom-management-commands/) called `runserver`
2. Implement it like this,

   ```
   from django.core.management.runserver import Command as BaseCommand

   class Command(BaseCommand):
       default_addr = "example.com"
       default_port = "port"
   ```

Change the code as necessary.

For those who are using `runserver_plus` package you can just set `RUNSERVERPLUS_SERVER_ADDRESS_PORT` in your settings file.

```
RUNSERVERPLUS_SERVER_ADDRESS_PORT = "example.com:port"
```